# show list of current weather of an array of different cities in ItemView

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a list of cities.

```
let Cities: [String] = [ "Eden", "Elizabethtown", "Lagos", "Dakar", "New York","Tokyo", "Delhi", "Shanghai", "Dhaka"]
```

Am using task modifier and  Open weather API to fetch data as shown below.

```
.task {
     do {
         for cityName in Cities{

         cityWeatherData = try await
         weatherManager.getCityWeather(cityName: cityName)
        }
         } catch {
         print("Error getting weather: \(error)")
   }
```

From the above code am calling a method getCityWeather passing city name, I dunno, if it's the collect idea or way, am just learning SwiftUI. Below is the getCityWeather method.

```
func getCityWeather(cityName: String) async throws -> RespondBody {

    
    guard let url = URL(string: "\(BASE_URL)q=\(cityName)&appid=\(OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY)&units=metric") else{
        fatalError("Wrong url")
    }
    
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)
    
    guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else {
        fatalError("Unable to fetch weather data")
    }
 
    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(CitiesRespondBody.self, from: data)

    return RespondBody
}
```

As from the above code, I have decoded JSON data using CitiesRespondBody and the codes run well. My question is how do I show the above cities weather ItemViewList?
My Item looks like this.

```
//calling 
CityItemView(weather: CitiesDefaultData)

//MARK: - body
var body: some View {
    HStack{
        Text(weather.name)
            .font(.headline)
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
        
        Spacer()
        
        
        Text(weather.main.temp.roundDouble() + "°")
            .font(.headline)
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
        
        Image(getIcon(icon: "\(weather.weather[0].icon)"))
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        
    }// : HStack
    .padding(12)
    .frame(height: 50, alignment: .center) 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Organise your code and when getting city data, return what you get from json decoding. You seem to copy part of code from different places on internet without building first your view and then your data model.